# Class initialization by Options

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a function for create user token, and I have some parameters the will install according to the type.
The main class is `ClaimsIdentity`
I created a dictonary that will give the details according to the keys. but I can't use ths way for installing `ClaimsIdentity`
what elegant, smart way I have?

```
private string CreateUserToken(UserDTO id, EmailOrPhone emailOrPhone)
{
    Claim claims;
    var emailOrphone = new Claim("fieldName", DateTime.Now.AddHours(12).ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MySecret_Nofshonit");

    var dic = new Dictionary<EmailOrPhone, Claim>()
                {
                    {EmailOrPhone.Phone, new Claim("expiredDate", DateTime.Now.AddHours(12).ToString("ddMMyyyy")) },
                    {EmailOrPhone.Phone, new Claim("fieldName", "Phone")  },
                    {EmailOrPhone.Email, new Claim("expiredDate", DateTime.Now.AddHours(48).ToString("ddMMyyyy")) },
                    {EmailOrPhone.Email, new Claim("fieldName", "Email")  },
                };

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        //Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3),
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {

                        new Claim("memberId", id.ToString()),
                        new Claim("creationDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")),
                        new Claim("expiredDate", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString("ddMMyyyy")),
                        // ....
        }),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    var encryptedTokenString = Cryptor.Encrypt(tokenString);

    return encryptedTokenString;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an exception?  Can we get a full reproducible example....  I do not understand your question

Comment: @Darkonekt I need that  `Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]` will get parameterst by options like `if (EmailOrPhone.Email)` so   `Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]` will have all the `Claim` under key `(EmailOrPhone.Email)` in the dictionary `dic`